# How do I inject the dependency of a dependency for a grails integration test?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a controller which calls a service which calls another service. I am trying to inject both of these dependencies into my integration test, but I can only get that to work for the first of the services.

What I've tried for an integration test:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
@TestMixin(IntegrationTestMixin)

class BookVacationTests extends GroovyTestCase{
    def travelAgentService
    def julie
    void testPlanTrip(){
        def bookVacationController = new BookVacationController()
        bookVacationController.travelAgentService = travelAgentService
        bookVacationController.travelAgentService.secretaryService = julie
        bookVacationController.planTrip()
        assertEquals(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, bookVacationController.response)
    }
}
```

What my controller looks like:

```
class BookVacationController {
    def travelAgentService
    def planTrip(){
        travelAgentService.makeSecretaryDoIt()
        render HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
    }
}
```

What my first service looks like:

```
@Transactional
class TravelAgentService {
    SecretaryService secretaryService
    def makeSecretaryDoIt(){
        secretaryService.bookTheTripPlease()
    }
}
```

What my SecretaryService interface looks like:

```
public interface SecretaryService {
    public void bookTheTripPlease();
}
```

What my second service looks like:

```
@Transactional
class Julie implements SecretaryService {
    public void bookTheTripPlease(){
        //...
    }
}
```

But I get a runtime exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'julie': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.lexmark.pigeon.ws.service.julie]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Why can't I do this?

Comment: All services should end with "Service". Try renaming to `JulieService`.

Comment: Ahh, ok, bad example then. This is a simplified example of my code, and in my actual code all services end with "Service". So there must be some other reason...